# Pourquoi un «puits» comporte-t-il un «s» ?

Tags: orthographe, latin

J'ai cru comprendre que le *t* de *puits* avait été ajouté afin de se rapprocher de sa base latine qui serait *pŭtĕus*, mais **qu'en est-il du *s*** ?

De ce que j'en sais c'est un mot qui est assez peu utilisé au pluriel, et de toute façon le mot *puits* dans un contexte singulier est bien considéré comme un nom commun singulier.

Answer (score 6):

En effet, d'après le [wiktionaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/puits) :

> **puits** /pɥi/ masculin, singulier et pluriel identiques

En googlant un peu j'ai trouvé cette [réponse yahoo](https://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080331015921AAKMEgu) :

> En latin le mot "puits" se dit "puteus", ce qui implique que le radical et -pute- et justifie la diphtongaison -puit-. Mais que fait-on de la longueur des syllabes? Le nom français vient de l'accusatif des mots latin donc puteum où le 2nd "u" est long. On peut donc suspecter (à défaut d'attester) que le mot à l'époque de Charlemagne se disait "puito" comme on ne peut faire disparaître la deuxième syllabe "teu/to".
>
> Ainsi quand en ancien français (XIe/XIIe siècles) on avait le nom au nominatif on devait sans doute dire "li puites" et non "li puiz" la voyelle empêchant la palatalisation. Et même si on disait "li puiz" l'oreille aurait gardé une mémoire de cette syllabe disparue ce qui signifie qu'en moyen français (XVe) la voyelle avait beau avoir disparu ("puits") la palatalisation ne se faisant plus à cette époque **le "s" est resté dans la forme écrite** avant de ne plus être prononcé de même que le "t" au XVIe siècle.

Answer (score 2):

Selon [cet article](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/orthographe/puit-ou-puits/) :

> L’explication de l’orthographe de « puits » serait à chercher dans ses
>   évolutions orthographiques successives. Comme le montre notre article
>   de dictionnaire, « puits » s’écrit d’abord « puz » ou « puiz » (XIIème
>   siècle), et on trouve la forme « puis » du XIème au XVIIème siècle. À
>   cette époque, on prononçait à l’oral le « s » final et cette
>   prononciation aurait mené à garder le « s » à l’écrit, avant qu’on
>   n’arrête de le prononcer. Le mot vient du latin puteus signifiant «
>   trou, fosse », ce qui explique que les grammairiens aient décidé
>   d’ajouter un « t » pour distinguer le mot de l’adverbe « puis ».