# Le « puits » : voyelles, « t » ?

Tags: étymologie, orthographe, évolution, ancien-français

Dans une autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13854) on se demande pourquoi le mot « puits » prend un « s »; ici on se demande depuis quand a-t-il sa graphie moderne, et pourquoi y trouve-t-on les voyelles (« ui ») qui diffèrent de la graphie latine de [*pŭtĕus*](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=puteus) ([*Lewis*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=puteus&la=la&can=puteus0#lexicon), [*DuCange*](http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/puteus)) ? A-t-on des explications supplémentaires au sujet de cet extrait de la rubrique étymologique au *TLFi* ?

> Du lat. *puteus* « trou, fosse », « puits d'eau vive », et « puits de
>   mine »; pour expliquer la voy. rad., on peut supposer l'infl. du frq.
>   **putti* (restitué d'apr. l'a. h. all. putti, v. FEW t. 9, p. 631; v. aussi F. de La Chaussée, *Init. à la phon. hist. de l'a. fr.*, 2e éd.,
>   p. 129), cf. cependant Fouché, p. 404.
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* - TLFi à « [*puits*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/puits) » ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tout d'abord on peut résumer avec deux phrases à la fin de la rubrique « puits » au *DHLF* (voir généralement [*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/puits), [*Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/puits)) :

> [...] Ainsi puits serait un exemple de ces formes hybrides dues au
>   bilinguisme de la France du Nord après l'invasion des Francs. La
>   graphie actuelle puits (XVIe s.) réintroduit un -t- étymologique pour
>   éviter l'[homographie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/homographie) avec puis.
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, A. Rey, ed. Le
>   Robert, « *puits* » ]

On [situe](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?t=19347) premièrement *puz* (v. 1112), *puiz* (v. 1120) et *puis* (v. 1131)<sup>1</sup>. On affirme que le « t » réapparaît formellement au XVIe siècle, pour contrer l'homographie avec *puis*.<sup>2</sup> Il s'agit aussi d'un cas particulier où, possiblement, un mot latin se transporte en ancien [haut-allemand](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langues_franciques#Parlers_franciques_de_l.27allemand_sup.C3.A9rieur) °*putti*, vers le [Francique](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieux-francique_%28langue_morte%29#Mots_fran.C3.A7ais_d.E2.80.99origine_mixte_latino-francique), lui aussi °*putti*, puis enfin au français.

Mais il y a d'autres explications et M. [Rey](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alain_Rey) partage une partie de son propos avec celui de M. [*P. Fouché*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Fouch%C3%A9), dans un [contexte](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_spirante_palatale_vois%C3%A9e) différent. Dans son article « [*De l'action dilatatrice du yod en gallo-roman*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k198921/f32.image) » dans la *Revue des langues Romanes* (1968), celui-ci passe en revue (pp.28-42) plusieurs théories au sujet de l'origine de la voyelle radicale dans puits et traite de la différence entre le français et les autres langues romanes. Il rejette l'influence du francique °*putti*, optant plutôt pour une « *dilatation conservatrice* » sous l'anticipation d'un premier « y » combinée à l'action assimilatrice d'un autre « y » en contact, pour expliquer la préservation du « u » latin (en gallo-roman septentrional).<sup>3</sup>

---

<sub>1. Au [*La Curne de Sainte-Palaye*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/previous/dictionnaire-lacurne/480/8/puis) (origines jusqu'à Louis XIV), on présente comme première citation à l'entrée « puis », l’œuvre de [Philippe de Beaumanoir](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_de_Beaumanoir_%281250-1296%29) (1250-1296) [*Coutumes de Beauvaisis*](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k58202250/f459.item.r=%22lor%20puis%22) XXI, 27 (idem *Littré*) : "*Si comme de lor moustiers refere et de lor caucies [chaussées] ramender, de lor puis et de lor gués maintenir*".</sub>

<sub>2. Voir aussi, [*Larousse*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/puits/65026/difficulte). Pour le « t », [*Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/puits) donne comme deux premières citations [Aubigné](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9odore_Agrippa_d%27Aubign%C3%A9) au XVIe. Autrement, aucun exemple à l'[entrée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/puits?idf=dmfXgXrmXpbdea;str=0) au *DMF* (1330-1500) ne contient le mot avec un « t ». En reculant, au complément du *Godefroy* (IX-XVe), on a (la totale) [*puiz*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/puiz) avec le sens qu'on lui connaît mais avec les graphies *puz*, *puc*, *puucz*, *pois*, *putz*, *puch*, *puus*, *poez*, *pus*, *poiz*, *pouche*, *puch*, *puich*, *puxe*, *puys*, *puichz*, *pouys*, et *puis*. Au dictionnaire, [*puit*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/puit), *pust* renvoient à [*put*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/previous/dictionnaire-godefroy/472/6/put) (sale, infect); on a le [*puitier*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/puit), *Putearius, qui fouit le puits, puitier*; on a [*putast*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/next/dictionnaire-godefroy/471/6/put), *putet* avec une acception particulière; [*puz*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/puz) renvoie à [*pui*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/pui) (puier, gravir; *mettre en pui*, *élever en honneur* [!]; société littéraire; contemporain [*puy*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/puy), géo.). On peut observer aussi des formes du verbe [*poeir*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/previous/complement-godefroy/364/10/poeir) (pouvoir) similaires au mot *puits*.</sub>

<sub>3. Cette phrase ne saurait rendre justice à son propos détaillé et je ne dispose pas de l'expertise requise pour le commenter et y extrapoler la raison exacte de la présence du « i », la réponse étant donc incomplète ; varia, voir aussi *étymologie [occitane](http://www.etymologie-occitane.fr/?s=puits)*, [*thesoc*](http://thesaurus.unice.fr/recMot/tableauResultat.php?question=puits), [*roussillonnais*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BfSYQQEmrbUC&lpg=PP1&dq=pierre%20fouch%C3%A9&pg=PA190#v=onepage&q=puits&f=false), [Fouché autre I](https://books.google.com/books?ei=y9dbVcnoLoLYtQWoooHgAw&id=TVo8AAAAIAAJ&dq=pierre%20fouch%C3%A9&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=puits), [II](https://books.google.com/books?id=zipcAAAAMAAJ&dq=editions%3AoSs3w-5qWQMC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=puits), [III](https://books.google.com/books?id=3e0dAAAAIAAJ&dq=editions%3AoSs3w-5qWQMC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=puits); [dict. langue d'*oïl*](https://archive.org/stream/glossairedelala01bosgoog#page/n411/mode/2up) à *puch*, et *pui* - « [pew](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=pew) » angl..</sub>

Comment: (+1) Un vrai *puits* de science ! ^^' Pardon mais il fallait que quelqu'un la fasse...

Comment: @RomainVALERI _Parler de puits_ hahah. (voir _Littré_ en fin de l'entrée). Merci.